# curl: how to encode file name?

Tags: bash, curl

When I run

```
curl  -J -O --location-trusted "http:..."
```

it correctly saves a file but the file name (the one from response) looks like `11%20-%204%20-%20....`. how can i tell curl to decode it and save that name with with spaces, brackets etc?

Answer (score 2):

Answer: You can't. At least not directly.

The `-O` (Capital "O") tells `curl` to name the file after the URL's final part after the last forward slash. If that contains encoded characters, your file name will have encoded characters. As it says in the manpage:

> There is no URL decoding done on the file name. If it has `%20` or other URL  encoded  parts  of the name, they will end up as-is as file name.

However, you can use the `-o` (Lowercase "o") option to give your file a proper name. You can use `sed` to remove encodings before you name the file:

```
URL=.....
file_name=$(sed 's/%20/ /g' <<<${URL##*/})
curl -o "$file_name" $URL
```

Note: There may be other [percent encoded characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters) in the file's name although `%20` to space gets the vast majority of them.